# Where can I find a good tutorial for PAB?

Tags: decentralized-applications, pab

Up till now, I can't find any tutorial on how to use PAB on the Internet.  I really want to try it out to develop Cardano Dapp. Anybody find good ones?

Answer (score 1):

[Lecture #6 and #10](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program) from Plutus Pioneer Program would be a good start although it might be a bit outdated because there has been many changes since the lectures were published, and PAB itself does not have an official stable release yet.

You can also check out [PAB components in the repo's README](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab#pab-components).

Comment: The issue with the lectures from the Plutus Pioneer Program is that they do not show how to interact with the PAB in a realistic way. The newest Demo is more helpful. It can be found here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab/demo/pab-nami

Comment: Thanks for that. However the link shows 404. The PAB README is too far away from a tutorial. I don't have a clue how integrate with my contract after studying it.

Comment: Newest demo https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami